# Web service (ASMX) proxy creation and reference.cs file not generating

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

i have developed a web service(ASMX) using c# version 4.0. which will just upload file to our web server. after deploying web service i create a win form project using .net v4.0 and there i create the proxy of my web service. after that i test the file upload process and found it is working. the problem start when i create a win form apps using .net v2.0 and when i create a proxy there of same web service then i saw proxy created without Reference.cs file. that is why i am not being able to call that web service. i am not being able to understand why Reference.cs file is not created when i try to create proxy using dotnet version 2.0.

so just tell me is there version specific issue. i guess problem occur because i develop this web service on dotnet v4.0 and proxy created on dotnet v2.0. please explain why Reference.cs file is not created. also guide me how could i solve this problem.

here i am posting my web service code. just have a look and tell me is there anything wrong.

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class FileUploader : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string UploadFile(byte[] f, string fileName)
        {
            // the byte array argument contains the content of the file
            // the string argument contains the name and extension
            // of the file passed in the byte array
            string uploadFolder = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"UPS_New\LabelImages\" + fileName;
            try
            {
                // instance a memory stream and pass the
                // byte array to its constructor
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(f);

                // instance a filestream pointing to the
                // storage folder, use the original file name
                // to name the resulting file
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(uploadFolder, FileMode.Create);

                // write the memory stream containing the original
                // file as a byte array to the filestream
                ms.WriteTo(fs);
                // clean up
                ms.Close();
                fs.Close();
                fs.Dispose();
                // return OK if we made it this far
                return "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // return the error message if the operation fails
                return ex.Message.ToString();
            }

        }

    }
```

please guide me...i am looking for suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is `version specific issue`,`when the client is build below the version of service then service cannot be accessed in the client`.to make this work ,`build the service in 2.0 framework and then do the reference`.it will then accept the service dll as it is build with same version as client.

in your case build the service in 2.0 first and then use that proxy which is build in 2.0 in your client.

Comment: i could fix this problem.i use wsdl.exe to create proxy of that service and then i use that proxy class in my winform apps developed using .net v2.0 and now i found everything is working fine without reference.cs file.